# How to highlight ListView item on touch?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a simple `ListView` and I want each of it items to be highlighted on user's touch. I thought this should happen by default but it isn't. Can you advice?

ListView xml:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view"     
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:divider="#206600"
    android:dividerHeight="2dp"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    >
</ListView>
```

And code of my Adapter:

```
private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Task> {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Task> list) {
            super(context, resource, list);
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;

            if (v == null) {
                v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            }

            Task task = taskList.get(position);

            /* Setup views from your layout using data in Object here */

            return v;
        }
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You may want to post your actual row layout code, but I suspect the problem will be that you set a background color on your list row. By default, the selectors are drawn behind the list items (which looks nicer, since the highlight color is behind the text). Either don't set a background color on your list items, or set it to draw the selector on top instead with ListView's [`drawSelectorOnTop`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:drawSelectorOnTop) XML attribute.

EDIT: If you really must have an opaque background for the default state and don't want to use `drawSelectorOnTop`, you  can also try this: Set a background on your list rows, but use a StateListDrawable to use `@android:drawable/list_selector_background` for all but the default state (you can define an xml file in your drawables folder for this; see the StateList [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)).

You could also nest a layout inside your outer backgrounded row layout with its background set to `@android:drawable/list_selector_background`; that way the background would draw on top of your background, but below the content.

Comment: Also, am I misunderstanding your basic question? Are you talking about the pressed state, or do you want a retained selected state after a touch and cancel (in which case RivieraKid's answer is more relevant)?

Comment: Removing background didn't do any changes so I was able to see selections now, thank you.

Comment: The ’drawSelectorOnTop’ attribute worked for me. Just note that a darker app theme will use a brighter selector and you may not see it if your row background is white. (Same thing in reverse if you're using a lighter app theme.)

Answer (score 2):

`ListView`s do not retain a visual indication of focus (or selection) while in touch mode. You will only see this when you use the hardware keyboard or controls to navigate your UI.

See the Google [Touch Mode](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2008/12/touch-mode.html) Android Blog article for more details.

So, if you are only using touch mode, you will never see focus or selection on `ListView`s.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has to do with the "Enabled" attribute of the items in the ListAdapter.

If your Adapter contains the code:

```
@Override
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
    return true;
}
```

Then each item should be clickable (and therefore should highlight on being touched).

Could you post details (and possibly code) of what kind of Adapter you're using for this list?

Comment: Hm, there's that and the sister method isEnabled(int position). If you add a call to that inside the getView() method and step through it with the debugger, you can find out if items being not Enabled is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for a few days. In the end, I have to create a widget that supports `Checkable` interface and return that widget/view in my adapter's `getiew()` function. And the listview needs to be in `ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE` (or possibly any other mode specified by `android:choiceMode`) for it to keep track of the choice made on the UI.

So in essence, all the following needs to be in place for the listview item to stay highlighted:

1. `ListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);`
2. `ListAdapter.getView()` return a view that implements `Checkable` interface
3. `ListView.OnItemClickListener` should call `setItemChecked(position, true)` to mark the item to be checked (and thus highlight it in the listview)

Hope this can help someone who is also struggling with this.