# ListView highlighter doesn't work over certain png's

Tags: android, listview

I've a layout for top (and bottom) elements which look like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/topbgprayer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/prayer_top" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/topleftpatchprayer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/topbgprayer"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/leftbgprayer"
        android:src="@drawable/prayer_top_left_patch" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/toprightpatchprayer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/prayer_top_right_patch" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/play_fill_free_download" />
    <ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/spare_play"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/spare_play" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDescr"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivImage"
        android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.05"

        android:layout_marginRight="30sp"
        android:text="Молитвы Утренние"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvBottom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="6dp"

        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tvDescr"
        android:text="12 МБ"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:typeface="sans" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

so, main idea is that on top elements there is a tiled image on top and two patches to smooth the corners.
For some reason, highlighter on a ListView doesn't highlight over that images, but highlight others. If I try to delete some of theese images - it highlights area where they were deleted. How can I fix that?

[image]

Comment: It looks like the content that highlights when it is clicked doesn't fill the complete height it is supposed to. Can you check if changing the height on certain items changes the behavior? Presumably the TextView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The highlight by default is drawn behind the list item view, therefore you see in behind the text and behind the triangle image (probably because the triangle image is transparent around the triangle), the other image is opaque so it hides the highlight.

What you should do is make a semi-transparent highlighter and draw it on top of the view. Check out this question for information on how to draw in on top: [How to highlight ListView item on touch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248210/how-to-highlight-listview-item-on-touch)

Alternatively you can disable the highlight completely, and add a hidden view on top of all the list item and use onTouchListener() to show it only when there is an ACTION_DOWN and hide it again when there is an ACTION_UP.